# Can not go back on main UIViewController after going to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, navigation

I've this sequence of controllers in storyboard

UIViewController embeded in navigation controller => button pressed(on UIViewcontroller) get UITableViewController(embeded in navigation controller) => row selected get another UITableViewController => row selected UIViewController

Now the problem is when I go to first UITableViewController I can not go back to Main UIViewController.
Do I have to add bar item button or is there other way.

Please help.
UPDATE -

Got it working, had embeded UITableViewController in navigation controller that's why it was not showing main view controller

Comment: Uhm... I'm confused.  A diagram illustration might help me.

Comment: Weird, if all view controllers are in the same stack inside a navigation controller the navigation bar with the back button should've been added automatically.

Comment: @user2916676 if you found any solution then please don't forget to post here it will help others.

Comment: is the segue between the view controller and the second navigationController a modal or a push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not hiding navigation bar or bar button then there is by default a button for back else Try this code to go back

```
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2] animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'd say that relying on view controller index to navigate between them is not a good approach since there are other ways of doing that using segues and unwind segues.

Comment: but why ... I always use this for custom back button it works perfectly, never gives me problem